# displaying a big object in AngularJS + handling changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

An internal tool is currently rendering a large object in AngularJS. The object represents a configurable product. A root node of the product contains various fields (strings, numbers) as well as 1) an array of child products and 2)an array of product definitions (what other child products can you add to this product). The structure repeats for all child products (they in turn contain an array of their own children and an array of product definitions).

Due to 10+ depth of object hierarchy the assembly of the DOM is handeled through a directive. It takes 10-15 seconds for the whole hierarchy of DOM elements to render on my machine. This, for now is acceptable (in the future we plan to change it so that the child elements render only after we expand an element on the parent).

We have an API that lets us add or delete a child on any level in hierarchy. The API returns back the updated root node with the whole hierarchy. This means that we have to re-render the whole hierarchy (again it takes 10+ seconds). I say we "have to" because an addition or removal of a product at any depth may influence any other nodes at any other level, including the root node (fields such as price for example), so it is not possible to just change an underlying object manually in AngularJS to reflect the requested change. I am looking for a solution that will enable me to update only those fields and nodes in hierarchy that have had any change made to them as the result of calling the modification API

Questions:

1. If I swap out the old root node with the new one in the directive, will the watchers detect the changes and update DOM changes only on those fields/nodes that had changes to them or will it take the same time as rendering the root node for the first time(meaning that the whole thing will be re-rendered because I swapped an underlying object with another one, which may actually field-for field contain same data, only with minor differences and 1 less/more object in hierarchy)?
2. (Provided the answer to #1 is negative, 100% re-rendering takes place)Would it be wise to write a function that takes both root nodes (old and new) and does a parallel iteration on them to trigger data change on the old root node (the one that has already been rendered and has watchers set up for it) based on data present on the new node?
3. Anyone has any other suggestions?

EDIT FOR EXAMPLE:
Simplified example:

Below is the sample product SoftwarePackageSubscription that has 2 actual child products (SecuritySoftware, AntiVirusSoftware) and 1 product definition that can be added to this root node (AccountingSoftware). For the given example SecuritySoftware does not have any children, nor can it have any, which is why it does not have any productDefinition attached to it. On the other hand AntiVirusSoftware does have a child called FileSystemAntivirus and it is also possible to add another child to it, which is why we have a productDefinition for NetworkAntivirus attached to it. (scroll past the sample code for continued text)

```
{
   "SoftwarePackageSubscription":{
      "name":"Subscription package 1",
      "id":"rootSubscriptionId",
      "productDefinitionId":"123-456",
      "parentId":"null",
      "childProducts":{
         "SecuritySoftware":{
            "name":"Sample Security Software",
            "id":"SecuritySoftwareID",
            "productDefinitionId":"111-111",
            "parentId":"rootSubscriptionId"
         },
         "AntiVirusSoftware":{
            "name":"Sample AntiVirus Software",
            "id":"AntiVirusSoftwareID",
            "productDefinitionId":"222-222",
            "parentId":"rootSubscriptionId",
            "childProducts":{
               "FileSystemAntivirus":{
                  "name":"Sample File System Antivirus",
                  "id":"FileSystemAntivirusId",
                  "productDefinitionId":"444-444",
                  "parentId":"AntiVirusSoftwareID"
               }
            },
            "Definitions":{
               "NetworkAntivirus":{
                  "name":"NetworkAntivirus",
                  "productDefinitionId":"555-555"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "Definitions":{
         "AccountingSoftware":{
            "name":"AccountingSoftware",
            "productDefinitionId":"333-333"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

We have an API that basically enables us to say this `addNode(parentId, productDefinitionId)`. So if I call addNode("AntiVirusSoftwareID","555-555") it will return the updated json

```
{
   "SoftwarePackageSubscription":{
      "name":"Subscription package 1",
      "id":"rootSubscriptionId",
      "productDefinitionId":"123-456",
      "parentId":"null",
      "childProducts":{
         "SecuritySoftware":{
            "name":"Sample Security Software",
            "id":"SecuritySoftwareID",
            "productDefinitionId":"111-111",
            "parentId":"rootSubscriptionId"
         },
         "AntiVirusSoftware":{
            "name":"Sample AntiVirus Software",
            "id":"AntiVirusSoftwareID",
            "productDefinitionId":"222-222",
            "parentId":"rootSubscriptionId",
            "childProducts":{
               "FileSystemAntivirus":{
                  "name":"Sample File System Antivirus",
                  "id":"FileSystemAntivirusId",
                  "productDefinitionId":"444-444",
                  "parentId":"AntiVirusSoftwareID"
               },
               "NetworkAntivirus":{
                  "name":"NetworkAntivirus",
                  "id":"NetworkAntivirusId",
                  "productDefinitionId":"555-555",
                  "parentId":"AntiVirusSoftwareID"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "Definitions":{
         "AccountingSoftware":{
            "name":"AccountingSoftware",
            "productDefinitionId":"333-333"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Notice how the NetworkAntiVirus moved from Product definitions to the actual child product list. Lets say nothing else can be added so the product definitions element has been removed from AntiVirusSoftware child. This is a very condensed example, in reality there are a lot of fields on every level in hierarchy that can be updated and influenced by lower/higher level modifications in hierarchy, which requires the whole hierarchy to be returned by API. I hope this provides more background to my questions.

Comment: Due to the seemingly quite complex model structure and your abstract explanation, I personally find it somewhat hard to wrap my head around the entire issue that shall be solved here. Maybe you could provide a (simplified) live example?

Comment: @Sprottenwels edited and updated with an example

Comment: "requires the whole hierarchy to be returned by API"  Can you clarify:  are you re-generating the entire data structure from the server every time any part of the data changes?   And are you rendering the entire structure with a single monolithic directive?

Comment: @DanielBeck its a yes for both questions. The server regenerated whole data on the backend and sends it over to front end. The data is rendered with 1 monolithic directive (which takes a lot of time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some tests and the result is that the watchers set up on the DOm elements actually do a perfect job of dirty checking the underlying data node even if you swap out the whole object. Only those nodes/fields will trigger re-rendering that had their underlying data changed, so the changes in DOM are almsost instant due to small difference between two objects (despite their big size).